# What makes a flat color: "flat"?

Tags: color, color-theory, color-spaces, flat-design

What kind of calculations are there are behind 'flat' colors? Where I can start to choose them effectively? What are the properties?

I found [this article on color theory](http://designmodo.com/color-psychology-web-design/). It's great but I'd like to know more about this field.